# sql recursive function - to find managers

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, recursive-query

Lets say I have the following table

```
User_ID  Manager_ID  
---------------------
Linda        Jacob  
Mark         Linda  
Kevin        Linda  
Steve        Mark  
John         Kevin
```

Basically the requirement is to pull all the managers under the user_id you are searching for. So for instance if I send in 'Linda' then it should return me:

```
'Mark', 'Kevin', 'Steve', 'John'
```

or if I send in 'Mark' then it should return me:

```
Steve
```

I have heard of recursive function but I am unsure of how to do this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use:

```
WITH hieararchy AS (
   SELECT t.user_id
     FROM YOUR_TABLE t
    WHERE t.manager_id = 'Linda'
   UNION ALL
   SELECT t.user_id
     FROM YOUR_TABLE t
     JOIN hierarchy h ON h.user_id = t.manager_id)
SELECT x.*
  FROM hierarchy x
```

Resultset:

```
user_id
--------
Mark
Kevin
John
Steve
```

Scripts:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[YOUR_TABLE](
 [user_id] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
 [manager_id] [varchar](50) NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO YOUR_TABLE VALUES ('Linda','Jacob')
INSERT INTO YOUR_TABLE VALUES ('Mark','Linda')
INSERT INTO YOUR_TABLE VALUES ('Kevin','Linda')
INSERT INTO YOUR_TABLE VALUES ('Steve','Mark')
INSERT INTO YOUR_TABLE VALUES ('John','Kevin')
```

Comment: Thanks this works perfectly, quick question. Is there anyway to put the results in a an array so I can use it within my select statement

Comment: @Jacob: You can join to the name of the CTE, like you would for any table or view

Answer (score 0):

The code example from [Recursive Queries Using Common Table Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx) on MSDN shows exactly that.