# applying a recursive function on a specific row in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, recursion

im trying to combine these two ideas

1. recursive function - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx
2. [SQL Call Stored Procedure for each Row without using a cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1656804/sql-call-stored-procedure-for-each-row-without-using-a-cursor)

actually i have the two working individually

i can get a recursive function to work
and i can get a stored procedure to work on one row
but im having a hard time figuring out 
how to get my recursive stored procedure to work on a selected row

i am also referencing this post:
[sql recursive function - to find managers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3859882/sql-recursive-function-to-find-managers)

so if i have a specific row

```
id    mngr_id    person_id
--    -------    ---------
12       1777          923
```

i want to count how many levels to the CEO which has a `mngr_id = null` 
(as in one of the above examples)

the second part of this question:
if i wanted to do this on a random number of specific rows
would this be the efficient way to do it?

[post edited for clarification]
this code (adjusted for my sample data above)
 
which is from the above example 1  is excellent and works well

```
GO
WITH levels (mngr_id, person_id, id, Level)
AS
(
-- Anchor member definition
    SELECT e.mngr_id, e.person_id, e.id, 0 AS Level
    FROM MyEmployees AS e
    WHERE mngr_id IS NULL
    UNION ALL
-- Recursive member definition
    SELECT e.mngr_id, e.person_id, e.id, Level + 1
    FROM MyEmployees AS e
    INNER JOIN levels AS d
        ON e.mngr_id= d.person_id
)
-- Statement that executes the CTE
SELECT mngr_id, person_id, id, Level
FROM levels 
where id=@whatever_random_id_i_choose  -- <---- pseudocode
GO
```

note:
the reason why im posting is cuase my pseudocode doesnt work
and breaks when person_id is not unique

thank you all for your input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet would be to use a recursive common table expression. This way you can use it in a view too.

```
WITH ORG_STRUCTURE
AS (
    SELECT 
         id
        ,mngr_id
        ,person_id
        ,0 AS c_level
    FROM occupancies
    WHERE person_id = @target_user_id


    UNION ALL

    SELECT
          id
        ,mngr_id
        ,person_id
        ,ORG.c_level  + 1 AS c_level
    FROM ORG_STRUCTURE ORG
        INNER JOIN occupancies MAN
            ON ORG.manager_id = MAN.person_id

    -- prevents recursion errors if you have an incomplete org structure
    WHERE c_level < 100
)

SELECT
     id
    ,mngr_id
    ,person_id
    ,MAX(c_level)
FROM ORG_STRUCTURE
WHERE mngr_id IS NULL
GROUP BY id
    ,mngr_id
    ,person_id
```

A recursive CTX can only go 100 layers deep, so if you have an incomplete org structure, you need to add a throttle where clause to the second query (see comment).

The group by and MAX() may not be required if you have a well formed org structure. You can put this in a stored proc @target_user_id. If you want to only return the distance from CEO, you can limit the select from CTE to something like:

```
SELECT
    ,MAX(c_level)
FROM ORG_STRUCTURE
WHERE mngr_id IS NULL
```

Comment: thank you for your response @tsarin - 
however im still not understanding how to do this for one specific row - in yr example - you are not travelling all the way up to CEO but rather a target id that could possibly not be the CEO and the specific row is not based upon the person_id but rather the id... i will adjust in my initial question

Comment: You can pass the starting ID in as a parameter, then add a condition to your select from the CTE. I will update my example to limit the query to return one row

Comment: hey @tsarin - ive added additional stuff to my post which more clarifies the issue i hope.  in yr test code - it looks like i will run into infinite recursion if i my person_id is not unique

Comment: If the person is not unique, do the duplicate rows have the same manager, or do they have a valid from/valid to date? If they have the same manager, you can do a GROUP BY in the CTE. If they have valid from/to dates, you can do a valid_from <= GETDATE() AND valid_to > GETDATE()

Comment: sometimes the person has the same manager sometimes not.  imagine you as an employee has worked for one manager in one company and another in another company or maybe both you and yr manager moved to a diff company but yr manager is still your manager

Comment: Is the organisation structure a tree format? By that, I mean will all reporting lines eventually make their way back to the CEO?

Comment: excellent @tsarin - this worked great - thanks so much!  ive also adjusted the question